# Excel.Worksheet.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@" Late Binding Warning

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a late binding warning on the below code, specifically the last line.

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkbook .Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

xlSheet.Name = "Summary"
xlSheet.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "@"
```

I'm not getting the error on the .Name property line so presumably it's an issue with .Columns?

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the New keyword in

```
Dim xlApp as New Excel.Application
```

Comment: Can you explain why that might resolve this? As far as I can tell that doesn't resolve a late-binding issue on xlSheet.

Comment: Not really as I'm still pretty new to Excel with code and I could very well be wrong but I did just find this post that might help. [Excel late Binding](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/option-strict-on-disallows-late-binding.2293645/)